# Удалить 2 последних HTML элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
<div> </div>
<style></style>
</body>
</html>
```

Где

```
<div></div>
<style></style>
```

Подгружаются с помощью плагина после загрузки страницы.
Как с помощью JS/jQuery удалить 2 любых последних элемента до

```
 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var bodyChilds = document.body.children, // Получаем всех потомков у тега боди
        bodyChildLen = bodyChilds.length-1; // Получаем количество потомков у тега боди


    bodyChilds[bodyChildLen].remove(); // Удаляем последний элемент в теге боди
    bodyChilds[bodyChildLen-1].remove(); // Удаляем предыдущий элемент в теге боди

});
```

Если не поможет, то ставим задержку

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       var bodyChilds = document.body.children, // Получаем всех потомков у тега боди
            bodyChildLen = bodyChilds.length-1; // Получаем количество потомков у тега боди
       bodyChilds[bodyChildLen].remove(); // Удаляем последний элемент в теге боди
       bodyChilds[bodyChildLen-1].remove(); // Удаляем предыдущий элемент в теге боди

    }, 10);

});
```

Comment: `children` - это живая коллекция. После выполнения строки `bodyChilds[bodyChildLen-1].remove();` количество элементов в ней изменится, и `bodyChilds[bodyChildLen]` вернет `undefined`.

Comment: @Grundy, согласен. Поправлю

Comment: А я уже сам поправил)